# Link one row to multiple rows in another table SQL CE

Tags: sql-server-ce

okay I'll be as clear as I possible can,

we have a supplier list that is quite frankly endless, therefore I decided to do a small app with combo boxes (C#). The app is set up such that the first combo box contains all the manufacturers (eg Intel, Gigabyte, Asus etc.), the second combo box will list the different suppliers that supply that product, and the third combo box will list the sales reps for the supplier.

So for eg: I want to find a supplier for Intel products:
Combo Box 1: Intel. 
Combo Box 2: Axiz, Rectron, Ingram Micro (I chose Axiz). 
Combo Box 3: Pete or Sarah or Michelle (I chose Sarah). 
Label that shows contact numbers from Sarah.

QUESTION: I'm limited to sql ce, my problem is how do I link one row in a table to multiple rows in another? So when I select a product in Combo Box 1 it must query the sql ce and display all suppliers in a supplier table that matches it.

Comment: Does my answer provide any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Your two entities suplier and manufacturer has a [many-to-many](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx) relation ship. So you have to create a new table to hold those relationships. Check the url for more info.